# How to make group by query with sum function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have `inventoryTransaction` table in SQL Server Like this:

```
productID StockLocationID TransactionType   Quantity
1046          1                "in"           100
1046          1               "out"            20
1046          2                "in"            70
1046          2               "out"            65
...
```

How to make a query, output like this:

```
productID  StockLocationID     stock
1046          1                 80
1046          2                 5
```

Comment: ProductID   StockLocationID   TransActionType    Quantity

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
SELECT 
    productID, 
    StockLocationID,
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN TransactionType = 'out' THEN -1 
            ELSE 1 
        END) * Quantity) AS stock
GROUP BY 
    productID, 
    StockLocationID
```

Answer (score 1):

The same but a little shortened eliminating unnecessary multiplication:

```
SELECT 
    productID, 
    StockLocationID,
    SUM(CASE TransactionType 
            WHEN 'out' THEN -Quantity 
            ELSE Quantity 
        END) AS stock
GROUP BY 
    productID, 
    StockLocationID
```